# Counting the number of matching digits in an array at different positions

Tags: java

Definitions:

- Bulls: If the matching digits in an array are at the same positions
- Cows: If the matching digits in an array are at different positions

For my assignment, I am trying to write functions that count the number of bulls and cows.

For example:

```
int[] secret = {2, 0, 6, 9};
int[] guessOne = {9, 5, 6, 2};
int[] guessTwo = {2, 0, 6, 2};
int[] guessThree = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
int[] guessFour = {1, 3, 4, 4, 0, 5};

getNumOfBulls(secret, guessOne) returns 1.
getNumOfBulls(secret, guessTwo) returns 3.
getNumOfBulls(secret, guessThree) raises an exception.
getNumOfBulls(guessThree, guessFour) returns 2.
getNumOfCows(secret, guessOne) returns 2.
getNumOfCows(secret, guessTwo) returns 0.
getNumOfCows(secret, guessThree) raises an exception.
getNumOfCows(guessThree, guessFour) returns 2.
```

I was able to complete the first part, but I am having trouble with counting the number of cows. My code includes the number of bulls in count of the cows such that getNumOfCows(secret, guessTwo) returns 3 instead of 0.

Here is my code:

```
// A method that gets the number of bulls in a guess

  public static int getNumOfBulls(int[] secretNumber, int[] guessedNumber) {

    // Initialize and declare a variable that acts as a counter

    int numberOfBulls = 0;

    if (guessedNumber.length == secretNumber.length) {

      // Compare the elements of both arrays at position i  

      for (int i = 0; i < guessedNumber.length; i++) {

        int guessedDigit = guessedNumber[i];
        int secretDigit = secretNumber[i];

        if (guessedDigit == secretDigit) {

          // Update the variable

          numberOfBulls++;
        }
      }
    }

    else {

      // Throw an IllegalArgumentException

      throw new IllegalArgumentException ("Both array must contain the same number of elements");
    }

    return numberOfBulls;
  }


  // A method that gets the number of cows in a guess --- TO BE FIXED

  public static int getNumOfCows(int[] secretNumber, int[] guessedNumber) {

    // Initialize and declare a variable that acts as a counter

    int numberOfCows = 0;

    if (guessedNumber.length == secretNumber.length) {

      // Loop through all the elements of both arrays to see if there is any matching digit located at different positions

      for (int i = 0; i < guessedNumber.length; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < secretNumber.length; j++) {

          int guessedDigit = guessedNumber[i];
          int secretDigit = secretNumber[j];

          if (guessedDigit == secretDigit) {

            // Update the varaible

            numberOfCows++;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    else {

      // Throw an IllegalArgumentException

      throw new IllegalArgumentException ("Both array must contain the same number of elements");
    }

    return numberOfCows;
  }
```

How can I adjust my second method in order to obtain the correct amount of cows?

Comment: you can construct map from your array, this way it would be much easier to achieve the described problem solution

Comment: @Maya what is the required output in your problem?

Comment: I don't think you have understood the problem guessTwo should return 1 (or 0 depending on the rules) and not 3 cows.

Comment: @SyedMehtabHassan The outputs are presented in the examples

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I know that guessTwo should return 0, but my code returns 3 instead. I can't figure out how to fix the problem

Comment: Ok but you wrote the other way around in the question. You might want to update it. And you might also want to explain better how to handle bulls and cows together if any such rules exists.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson No, I wrote it correctly. You might have read it too fast

Comment: Your example was correct yes, I got confused by the text under it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Counting the number of common elements in integer arrays located at different positions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55121991/counting-the-number-of-common-elements-in-integer-arrays-located-at-different-po)

Answer (score 0):

Just adding a condition i != j will solve your problem so that the position of elements will not be same.
for (int i = 0; i < guessedNumber.length; i++) {

```
    for (int j = 0; j < secretNumber.length; j++) {

      int guessedDigit = guessedNumber[i];
      int secretDigit = secretNumber[j];

      if ( i != j && guessedDigit == secretDigit) {

        // Update the varaible

        numberOfCows++;
      }
    }
```

Comment: @SyedMehtabHassan Your code eliminates the number of bulls in the cows count. However, getNumOfCows(secret, guessTwo) will still return 1 instead of 0 since the value at guessTwo[3] matches secret[0].

Comment: @Maya isn't it should return 1 as there are 2 at two positions?

Comment: The value 2 at index 0 of the secret array counts as a bull, thus it cannot be considered as a cow as well

Comment: @Maya you just have to add another check in the if condition guessedNumber[ i ] !=secretNumber[ i ] and your problem will be solved

Answer (score 0):

This solution merges the two functions into one since we must keep track of what numbers in the secret has already been marked as bull or cow. This means that it will return an array of 2 ints (bulls & cows) rather than an int. For clarity I have assumed the arrays are the same size. This check can of course be added back or even better performed before the method is called.

```
public static int[] getNumOfBullsAndCows(int[] secretNumber, int[] guessedNumber) {
    int max = secretNumber.length;
    int cows = 0;
    int bulls = 0;
    int[] checked = new int[max];
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        if (secretNumber[i] == guessedNumber[i]) {
          bulls++;
          checked[i] = 1;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
      if (checked[i] == 1) {
        continue;
      }
      for (int j = 0; j < max; j++) {
        if (secretNumber[i] == guessedNumber[j]) {
          cows++;
          checked[i] = 1;
        }
      }
    }
    return new int[]{bulls, cows};
}
```

---

Alternative take, use the original method in the question to count bulls and use my solution only to count cows

```
public static int getNumOfCows(int[] secretNumber, int[] guessedNumber) {
    int max = secretNumber.length;
    int cows = 0;
    int[] checked = new int[max];
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        if (secretNumber[i] == guessedNumber[i]) {
          checked[i] = 1;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
      if (checked[i] == 1) {
        continue;
      }
      for (int j = 0; j < max; j++) {
        if (secretNumber[i] == guessedNumber[j]) {
          cows++;
          checked[i] = 1;
        }
      }
    }
    return cows;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to keep the header of the method the same and return int instead?

Comment: @What do you mean, to have two methods instead of one? (I now see that I missed to rename the method to something more meaningful)

Comment: Instead of returning an array, I would like to have 2 methods that return int

Comment: @Maya Sure, that is more of an implementation detail, you could leave the count bulls method as it is and use the above method only for counting cows. I just wanted to avoid doing similar things twice.

Comment: My bad just saw it

Comment: @joakiemdanielson I haven't had time to go over it yet since I am currently working on another method

Answer (score 0):

For the getNumOfCows method, use the same code for the getNumOfBulls method, but in the for loop, call another method called contains().

The contains() method takes as input an array of integers and a specific integer. The method returns true if the specified integer is an element of the given array, and false otherwise.

```
public static boolean contains(int userInput[], int specificInteger){

    int[] secretNumber = userInput;
    int guessedDigit = specificInteger;

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {

        if(input[i] == element) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;

}
```

To write the getNumOfCows method, I will copy and paste the getNumOfBulls method above and add my contains() method inside it.

```
public static int getNumOfCows(int[] secretNumber, int[] guessedNumber) {

    // Initialize and declare a variable that acts as a counter
    int numberOfCows = 0;

    if (guessedNumber.length == secretNumber.length) {

      // Compare the elements of both arrays at position i  
      for (int i = 0; i < guessedNumber.length; i++) {

        int guessedDigit = guessedNumber[i];
        int secretDigit = secretNumber[i];

        if (contains(secretNumber, guessedNumber[i]) {
          // Update the variable
          numberOfCows++;
        }
      }
    }

    else {
      // Throw an IllegalArgumentException
      throw new IllegalArgumentException ("Both array must contain the same number of elements");
    }

    return numberOfCows;
}
```