# Counting the number of common elements in integer arrays located at different positions

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, continue

For my assignment, I need to write a method that returns the number of cows (see definition below) found between 2 arrays. If the input arrays have a different number of elements, then the method should throw an IllegalArgumentException with an appropriate message.

A bull is a common number in int arrays found at the same position while a cow is a common number in int arrays found at different position. Note that if a number is already a bull, it cannot be considered as a cow.

For example, considering the following arrays:

```
int[] secret = {2, 0, 6, 9};
int[] guessOne = {9, 5, 6, 2};
int[] guessTwo = {2, 0, 6, 2};
int[] guessThree = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
int[] guessFour = {1, 3, 4, 4, 0, 5};

1) getNumOfCows(secret, guessOne) returns 2
2) getNumOfCows(secret, guessTwo) returns 0
3) getNumOfCows(secret, guessThree) returns an exception
4) getNumOfCows(guessThree, guessFour) returns 2
```

My method seen below works perfectly for examples 1 and 3, but there is a problem with examples 2 and 4 such that getNumOfCows(secret, guessTwo) returns 1 instead of 0 because the element at secret[0] and guessTwo[3] is considered a cow. Could anybody help me fix my code?

```
// A method that gets the number of cows in a guess --- TO BE FIXED

  public static int getNumOfCows(int[] secretNumber, int[] guessedNumber) {

    // Initialize and declare a variable that acts as a counter

    int numberOfCows = 0;

    // Initialize and declare an array

    int[] verified = new int[secretNumber.length];

    if (guessedNumber.length == secretNumber.length) {

      // Loop through all the elements of both arrays to see if there is any matching digit

      for (int i = 0; i < guessedNumber.length; i++) {

        // Check if the digits represent a bull

        if (guessedNumber[i] == secretNumber[i]) {

          verified[i] = 1;
        }
      }

      for (int i = 0; i < guessedNumber.length; i++) {

        // Continue to the next iteration if the digits represent a bull

        if (verified[i] == 1) {

          continue;
        }

        else {

          for (int j = 0; j < secretNumber.length; j++) {

            if (guessedNumber[i] == secretNumber[j] && i != j) {

              // Update the variable

              numberOfCows++;

              verified[i] = 1;

            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

    else {

      // Throw an IllegalArgumentException

      throw new IllegalArgumentException ("Both array must contain the same number of elements");
    }

    return numberOfCows;
  }
```

Comment: Why should secret[0] and guessTwo[3] is not considered a cow? They are not bull because they are not in the same location,they are in the different locations and same number. This satisfies your definitions.

Comment: @Y.Kakdas probably because there's also a 2 at position 0 in both arrays so it's already considered a bull.

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55079127/counting-the-number-of-matching-digits-in-an-array-at-different-positions and I believe you find a correct answer there even if it hasn't been approved yet.

Comment: Your code needs a way of storing which elements are considered bulls as to not compare them with any other elements to find erroneous cows.

Comment: @Y.Kakdas Because secret[0] is already considered a bull with guessTwo[0]

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Basically, you have to create another array to store the elements that are already considered as bulls in order to not compare them again

Comment: And that is what I did in my answer in the linked question. I have two versions in my answer and the second one returns number of cows but both uses an array to keep track of the bulls

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Thanks. I'll try it once I have the chance and let you know if it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First go through and mark all bulls using a separate array to make sure a position that is a bull also get counted as a cow

```
public static int getNumOfCows(int[] secretNumber, int[] guessedNumber) {
    int max = secretNumber.length;
    int cows = 0;
    int[] checked = new int[max];
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        if (secretNumber[i] == guessedNumber[i]) {
          checked[i] = 1;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
      if (checked[i] == 1) {
        continue;
      }
      for (int j = 0; j < max; j++) {
        if (secretNumber[i] == guessedNumber[j]) {
          cows++;
          checked[i] = 1;
        }
      }
    }
    return cows;
}
```

---

*Now that this answer is accepted the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55079127/counting-the-number-of-matching-digits-in-an-array-at-different-positions) can be voted to be closed as a duplicate*

I am posting my answer from a duplicate question here and if this get approved then the other one can get closed as a duplicate.

Comment: For if (secretNumber[i] == guessedNumber[j]), we don't need to include i !=j ? Also, when you initiate checked[i] to 1, it can be any random number?

Comment: Elements in an int array are always initiated to 0. So in my code they are either 0 or 1. The `i != j` check is not needed since it is implicitly checked in `if (checked[i] == 1)`

Comment: I updated my code with your ideas, but it still gives me the same output. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: @Elizabeth when I run this code with the values in the question I get the right answer, 0 cows for test 2 and 2 cows for test 4

Comment: @Elizabeth, no I didn't notice you had updated it so it was my own.

Comment: Can you check what I have done wrong with my updated code please

Comment: @Elizabeth In the last for loop you have switched `i` and `j` in the if condition compared to my code. `guessedNumber[i] == secretNumber[j]` should be `guessedNumber[j] == secretNumber[i]`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that an element that is multiple times in at least one array will not be handled correctly.

A possible solution idea might be this one:

1. Create a cow list.
2. Iterate through both arrays and add **every** element that is in both arrays and has not been added yet. (note: complexity is n²)
3. Now that all **possible cows** are in the list, iterate through the array positions with the same index and if you find a bull, remove the number from the cow list.
4. Now the cow list contains only cows.

This solution might be a bit slower than your current one, but I think it's working properly.